# Zooming in and out in Direct3D

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I have a 3D scene and I want to be able to zoom in and out. What implementations are good, and which has some flaws? Will I be changing viewport, clipping panes? I totally don't know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "zooming" refers to adjusting the view of a 2d image.

In a 3d scene I do not know what you mean with zooming. Probably moving the camera is what you are looking for? http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/camera.html

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that whatever stuff I set with the DirectX, nothing happens. I've tried this before, but for some reason it does not work. That made me thing I got it wrong... I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a camera-like zoom, just change the camera viewing angle. This is usually set to around 45 degrees, but making it smaller will zoom into the image.